# Prevent onenote text edition if written by a particular user

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2016

I want to allow other users to add and delete their own text, but I want to prevent that they delete the text written by me. Is such thing possible?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

No, it is NOT possible.

Either you give users permission to edit a WHOLE notebook, or not, you can't manage rights within a notebook.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-permissions-for-a-notebook-on-onedrive-b9600ccf-045a-40e6-9913-4a7eb02869a5

Comment: But for instance, would it be possible to see if a user deleted something? How can I be sure that nothing that I wrote was deleted?